# Whether a function has an inverse and horizontal line test

Tags: functions

Apologize for naive question, but I got mixed answers regarding this one.

The inverse of $f$ exists if and only if $f$ is bijective. Horizontal line test is a test used to determine whether a function is injective (i.e., one-to-one).

However, I read many answers that to determine whether $f$ has an inverse we should apply horizontal line test. What if the function passes horizontal line test, but is not surjective? Why can we still use horizontal line test to determine whether $f$ has an inverse?

Comment: May I ask in what course you're taking that this question is arising in?

Comment: It was for introduction to real analysis, but does the usage of horizontal line test differ with course?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of math classes where you're told to use the horizontal line test, you're working with 2-dimensional graphs in the plane and "has an inverse" typically means you can define a function $f^{-1}$ which maps points from the image of $f$ to the domain of $f$. This is good enough for those types of classes because the teachers just want you to know the concept (of an inverse).

As you move on and become more advanced the concept of an inverse also becomes more rigorous and needs a better definition. Take any curve in the family of logistic curves for example - a tool evoked when discussing population growth (such a curve could be given by the function $\frac{e^x-1}{e^x+1}$). We think of logistic curves, when viewing them as functions, as mapping real numbers to other real numbers; but there is no function which maps every real number back to its input according to the logistic curve, because not every real number will be mapped to when we input some point on the logistic curve. So it kind of doesn't have an inverse. There is also a distinction to be made between codomain and image. The image of $f(x)=\frac{e^x-1}{e^x+1}$ is all real numbers between $1$ and $-1$ including those two numbers themselves, whereas the codomain of $f$ could be said to be any larger space containing all numbers from $-1$ to $1$. So codomains aren't unique. Thus asking "is $f$ invertible?" is weird. A better question would be "Is $f$ an invertible function from the real numbers to the real numbers?". So the invertibility (and surjectivity in particular) of a function depends on the codomain you're giving it.

In summary, know your context. If you're at high school level, or just exploring math alone for fun, ignoring surjectivity may absolutely be fine, while at the advanced level it is not and the horizontal line test proves to be inadequate, as you say. Understanding the large role of formalism in math, it is certainly vital that you take surjectivity to be part of invertability, but keep a note that in some less rigorous contexts this is ignored.

Perhaps someone else can explain it better - feel free to leave a comment.

Comment: I wanted to mention that the horizontal line test remains relevant as a way to show that a function is *not* invertible. If a function fails the horizontal line test, it is not injective and therefore cannot be bijective since all bijections are injections (the converse is not true). If a function passes the horizontal line test, we know it is injective and that a left inverse exists. Therefore, the horizontal line test can best be thought of as a criterion for the existence of a left inverse, which is necessary but not sufficient for a two-sided inverse.

Answer (score 1):

You can always restrict the codomain to make a function surjective. So if $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is injective then the same function but with codomain $f(X)$, denote it $g:X \rightarrow f(X)$ where $g(x)=f(x) \: \forall x \in X$, is surjective and thus bijective. So you can get an inverse $g^{-1}:f(X) \rightarrow X$.